# Why RDS with Postgres performance issues, while fetching data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

In Rails web application there is big performance problem issue on RDS compared to Digital Ocean:

**Application Configuration:**

```
Ruby 1.9.3 
Rails 3
PostgreSQL 9.3
```

I have database which is having records approx 500 million. All data is well indexed and optimized. When I am selecting of the data from heavy tables in database, same query is taking **5-10 mins** approx on "digital ocean" and **65-70 mins** on Amazon RDS server.

I am having existing server with configuration below:

**Server Configuration:**

```
Hosted on server: Digital Ocean
Storage: 1 TB
RAM: 96 GB
Processor: 24 core
```

The above configuration is cost expensive with "Digital Ocean". So I created new server on Amazon with RDS.

So please help.

Why **Amazon RDS for PostresSql causing this much of big time difference** in DB operations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what size instance are you using with RDS?

Comment: In addition, how I/O sensitive is your workload?

Comment: To get close to your hardware set up, you would need to be using db.m2.4xlarge or db.cr1.8xl instance sizes.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan RDS instance size is 1 TB.

Comment: @datasage IOPS in RDS is 3000, also I am using db.m3.xlarge instance class on RDS.

Comment: @SumitMunot, provisioned storage size does not matter, the instance size you are using does. Which size are you using? It should be db.m2.4xlarge or db.cr1.8xl to get similar performance to your digital ocean hardware.

Comment: @SumitMunot You updated your comment after I posted my last one. Your instance size is much lower performance compared to what you were using at digital ocean.

Comment: @datasage, thanks!! +1 on your comment..will it improve performance?

Comment: @SumitMunot There isnt any instance size that matches exactly what you had, but these two: db.m2.4xlarge or db.cr1.8xl are the closest. MySQL is much faster when more of its work can be done in memory vs disk, your previous hardware had 96 GB, your RDS instance has about 15 GB.

Comment: @datasage yeah cool..so will it be possible on Amazon to use this much of Hardware?

Comment: Switch your instance size to db.m2.4xlarge and test your performance again.

Comment: i.e exactly the same hardware that I am using on "Digital Ocean"...Also it seems from the documentation the instance class "db.m2.4xlarge" is near about same as digital ocean.

Comment: Documentations are given on this link..http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html

Comment: Please update the original question to make the RDS instance type you are using explicit in the question.